# How to get confirmation of an action in a web page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On an ASPX page I have a "Delete" button that is wired up to a method that calls for the current record to be deleted.  The button is wired up in this way:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteUser" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDeleteUser_Click" />

protected void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DeleteUser();
}
```

I want to interrupt the delete action with a confirmation dialog, and if it is confirmed then the delete method is called.  Presumably I would put an OnClientClick method in there.

```
OnClientClick="confirmDelete();" 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmDelete(){
        var msg = "This will delete this AR Contact.  Are you sure you wish to do this.";
        if (confirm(msg)){
            // Do something here that causes the delete method on the server to be called
        }
    }
</script>
```

This raises an OK/Cancel dialog, and clicking Cancel obviously leads to nothing happening, but what if OK is clicked?  How is the Delete method on the server to be called?  I suppose that I could do a window.open onto a page that did the actual delete, and I can do that, but is there a way to submit to the server-side delete method from JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmDelete(){
        var msg = "This will delete this AR Contact.  Are you sure you wish to do this?";
        return confirm(msg);
    }
</script>
```

And make sure this attribute is on your button.

```
OnClientClick="return confirmDelete();"
```

Confirm returns true if the user clicks yes. It returns false if the user hits no. So you just return that, and it will automatically proceed to the server side function if the client side function returned true.

Comment: Actually, it proceeds to the server-side function regardless of whether OK or Cancel is clicked.  There doesn't seem to be a way to tell which one the user clicked at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript confirm will not call the server method if the user cancels.  If the user clicks ok, the javascript confirm would allow the button to send its request to the server.

You don't need to worry about opening a new page, etc.

Sample 1:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteUser" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDeleteUser_Click"
     OnClientClick="return confirm('This will delete this AR Contact.  Are you sure you wish to do this?');" />
```

And leave your server-side code the same.

```
protected void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DeleteUser();
}
```

Sample 2:
If you have multiple items that can raise the same confirmation message, go ahead and do it the way you had it.  However, it would look like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteUser" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDeleteUser_Click"
     OnClientClick="return confirmDelete();" />
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmDelete(){
        var msg = "This will delete this AR Contact.  Are you sure you wish to do this.";
        return confirm(msg);
    }
</script>
```

When you `return` the confirm's result, it should be seen by ASP.NET's postback javascript.  If confirm or your confirmDelete method returns false, then the postback should be skipped.